# In Transformers, why didn't Optimus use the Shard of the Allspark to heal Jazz?

Tags: transformers, transformers-2007

In the final battle of Michael Bay's *Transformers*, Jazz, Optimus Prime's second in command, is torn in half by Megatron. After the battle is completed, Ratchet and Ironhide bring the fallen Autobots parts to Optimus, and inform him that they could not heal the damage done to Jazz.

During the battle, Sam had killed Megatron by forcing the Allspark Cube into Megatron's Spark, destroying both the Cube and Megatron. A single Shard of the Cube remained, which Optimus picked up from Megatron's body.

Earlier in the movie, we see the Decepticon hacker, Frenzy, is fully repaired from being little more than a head by simply being in the same room as the Allspark Cube. As seen in *Revenge of the Fallen*, the Shard is stolen by Decepticons, and used to revive Megatron. Why didn't Optimus use the power of the Allspark Shard to repair Jazz?

Comment: Because (and you must imagine this as being said by Kanye West) Michael Bay doesn't care about black transformers!

Comment: @KevinHowell - LOL now imagine that being said by Blaster!

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlackDudeDiesFirst

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Frenzy is a sort of special case.

From [TFWiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Frenzy_%28Movie%29):

> Frenzy is exceptionally hard to kill, due to the fact that he possesses a de-centralized, modular nervous system. In essence it means that even if he suffers critical injuries—such as getting his head severed, which seems to be a not-infrequent problem for him—he can continue to function.

Megatron had been defeated and killed, but his body was still pretty much whole. If Megatron was reactivated, he would just come back to life. Jazz, on the other hand, had been torn into two pieces. If he was reactivated without extensive (apparently difficult/impossible) repairs, his body may not function due to essential systems not being connected.

Comment: Also, the shards of the AllSpark were discovered later. And the method to reactivate a Transformer using that shard was known only to "The Doctor".

Comment: In addition to that there are some mentionings that megatron ate jazzs spark (although in the film that is not shown)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 primary differences there between Megatron/Frenzy and Jazz.

1st even when Megatron is revived they needed spareparts first from another transformer to repair him and only then they reactivated him with the allspark.
One could argue there the dead decepticons were too badly damaged to be able to give spare parts.

2nd Though not explicitely shown in the film itself Megatron ate the spark of Jazz when he killed him. Thus there was nothing left that could be revived, contrary to what was up with Megatron, Bumblebee and Frenzy.

Thus all in all the situation was so different that it was not possibl to resurrect Jazz at all.

Answer (score 1):

During the Transformers Titan comics, Ratchet did heal Jazz with the Allspark shard. However, it corrupted him because the Allspark was already corrupted by Megatron.